# boost::regex matches[] c++

Tags: regex, boost

I have a code that returns all matches from a regex but i can't use matches, for example i want to cout just the second result like match[1] or match[2]

```
std::string text("5345345345334 456456454353");
boost::regex regex("[0-9]{10}");

boost::sregex_token_iterator iter(text.begin(), text.end(),regex,0);
boost::sregex_token_iterator end;

for( ; iter != end; ++iter ) {

std::cout<<*iter<<'\n';
```

is there any way to convert *iter to matches[] so i can use each match ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct answer:
just create the `std::vector` from iterators you have:

```
std::vector<std::string> v(iter, end);
```

Full code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  std::string text("5345345345334 456456454353");
  boost::regex regex("[0-9]{10}");

  boost::sregex_token_iterator iter(text.begin(), text.end(),regex,0);
  boost::sregex_token_iterator end;

  std::vector<std::string> v(iter, end);
  std::cout << "0: " << v[0] << ", 1: " << v[1] << std::endl;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

And the output is:

```
0: 5345345345, 1: 4564564543
```

Comment: I tried compile your code but it doesn't output anything

Comment: Sorry, I missed the point and provided the wrong answer first. The correct way is to use `regex_search` in a loop or just create a vector from iterators